# Attaching event to dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have some dynamically generated from a javascript plugin. It creates some divs with class `.someclass` which wraps some existing divs. I want to add some class to `.someclass` children. So I put

```
$(document).ready('.icheckbox',function(){
            if($(this).children().first().hasClass('checked')){
                console.log('test');
            }
        })
```

but the console shows nothing. So I tried

```
$('body').on('.icheckbox',function(){
            if($(this).children().first().hasClass('checked')){
                console.log('test');
            }
        })
```

but it doesn't work either. Someone could help ?

Edit : here's the `html` code :

```
<div class="controls">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="notif_user_like" id="notif_user_like" class="checkbox checked" value="1" /> <label for="notif_user_like" class="checkboxLabel">some text</label>
                </div>
```

and here's how the code turns into after the javascript was processed :

```
<div class="controls">
                    <div class="icheckbox" style="position: relative;"><input type="checkbox" name="notif_user_like" id="notif_user_like" class="checkbox checked" value="1" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></ins></div> <label for="notif_user_like" class="checkboxLabel">some text</label>
                </div>
```

Comment: firstly, there is no tag 'document'. You are lucky pseudo ready event to be fired on anything, even empty object. Secondly, i think you want: `$('body').on('change','.icheckbox',function(){...})`

Comment: Can you post the html structure? Also it should be `$(document).ready` note the removal of the quotes around document

Comment: The syntax for `on` is [`$(delegate).on(events, selector, callback)`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: @A.Wolff You are correct.

Comment: @mituw16 sorry, it was a typo

Comment: @A.Wolff I tried it with `$('body').on('change'` but it didn't work

Comment: @user1611830 you have to provide relevant HTML code too. What are '.icheckbox' elements? And check your console for error. BTW, `it didn't work` doesn't mean anything

Comment: @user1611830 so my first comment works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/K2Qwe/

Comment: @A.Wolff so there's must be something going wrong. I'll try to find !

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('change', '.icheckbox', function (e) {
        if ($(this).children().first().hasClass('checked')) {
            console.log('test');
        }
    });
});
```

The `on` method is used for delegation of event handling, which is what you want for dynamically added elements as they may not exist when the handler is bound.

The form is `$(parentElementSelector).on(event, triggerElementSelector, handler);`

You can read the API at http://api.jquery.com/on/

**UPDATE**:

As pointed out by [A. Wolff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff), you don't really need to wait for the DOM to be loaded. You can simply use `document` as the parent element selector:

```
$(document).on('change', '.icheckbox', function (e) {
    if ($(this).children().first().hasClass('checked')) {
        console.log('test');
    }
});
```

A [perhaps] better method (and one I typically implement in my own projects) is to use a closer ancestor as the parent element selector:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.controls').on('change', '.icheckbox', function (e) {
        if ($(this).children().first().hasClass('checked')) {
            console.log('test');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i was just posting that +1 Op could delegate to document without having to wait for DOM ready or better use closest static container as delegate level inside document ready handler. OP should read DOC in any way

Comment: True, no real need to wait for DOM ready. Typed it out of habit.

Comment: For binding to body, you still have to wait for BODY beeing in DOM, so cannot put code in HEAD section, and so your answer is accurate. I was talking about document which will be available in all case